# Returning UID in Firebase query

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

The following query below returns me a collection of data based on a user id. How do I do I make sure it returns the uid of each document in the query.

```
  getWebsitesByUserId(id) {
    return this.afs.collection('websites', ref => ref.where('createdBy', '==', id)).valueChanges();
  }
```

I understand that it involves something like this:

```
  return this.afs.collection('websites').doc(id).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(action => {
    const data = action.payload.data();
    const uid = action.payload.id;
    return {uid, ...data};
  }));
```

Just not sure how to implement in a query.

Comment: Please edit the question to show more specifically what your input document(s) look, what you're expecting as output, and how your code is doing that's not what you expect.  Also please be clear what you mean by "uid".  When dealing with Firebase products, UID usually means the "user ID" assigned to users signing in with Firebase Auth.  Did you actually just mean "document ID"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this pull request](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/pull/1976) on the AngularFire Repo now there is an option that you can pass a string to the valueChanges method on a collection reference.

This string will be the name of the property that will hold the IDs of the documents.

For example:

```
collectionRef.valueChanges('myIdKey').subscribe()
```

Would emit:

```
emits [ { myIdKey: 'MrfFpRBfWLTd7LqiTt9u', ...data }, ... ]
```

So in your situation I guess it would be something like this:

```
 getWebsitesByUserId(id) {
    return this.afs.collection('websites', ref => ref.where('createdBy', '==', id)).valueChanges('uid');
  }
```